# C# checkBox Logic .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write this Program that gives the user the checkBox and then the user chooses One or Two and the Program will return the answer accordingly. but the program is not accepting the && Operator. if the user checks two boxes the program is only returning the result of the first checkBox not the second. it is not even adding.

This is the Code:

```
    private double Oillube()
    {

        //checking if the Oil is checked
        if (oilChbox.Checked)
        {
            return OIL_CHANGE;
        }

        //checking if the lube is checked
        if (lubeChbox.Checked)
        {
            return LUBE_JOB;
        }

        //if they are both checked
        if(lubeChbox.Checked && oilChbox.Checked)
        {
            //Creating Variables sum to hold the value of the two
            double sum;

            sum = OIL_CHANGE + LUBE_JOB;

            //returning sum
            return sum;

        }
        else
        {
            //just returning to get ride off the red line under the Method
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lubeChbox.Checked && oilChbox.Checked` condition needs to go first, as it is the more specific of the two.

The way you have it now if either `lubeChbox.Checked` is true, or `oilChbox.Checked` is true it will return before reaching the `lubeChbox.Checked && oilChbox.Checked` condition, meaning there is no situation in which it could ever reach the condition unless both were false.

This is why it is typically a bad idea for people to use `return` in this manner unless they fully understand the flow of the code they want to achieve.

Here's the corrected code:

```
private double Oillube()
{
    //if they are both checked
    if(lubeChbox.Checked && oilChbox.Checked)
    {
        //Creating Variables sum to hold the value of the two
        double sum;

        sum = OIL_CHANGE + LUBE_JOB;

        //returning sum
        return sum;

    }

    //checking if the Oil is checked
    if (oilChbox.Checked)
    {
        return OIL_CHANGE;
    }

    //checking if the lube is checked
    if (lubeChbox.Checked)
    {
        return LUBE_JOB;
    }

    //just returning to get ride off the red line under the Method
    return 0;
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use tertiary operators for this situation like so:

```
private double Oillube()
{
    return (lubeChbox.Checked ? LUBE_JOB : 0) + (oilChbox.Checked ? OIL_CHANGE : 0);
}
```

A tertiary operator works the same as an `if` statement only they work inline.

So this:

`(lubeChbox.Checked ? LUBE_JOB : 0)`

is equivalent to this pseudo-code:

`if(lubeChbox.Checked) { LUBE_JOB } else { 0 }`

[Dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/277Lun)

Answer (score 1):

Since the AND condition is more restrictive than the others, you should check it first. Like this:

```
private double Oillube()
    {
        //if they are both checked
        if(lubeChbox.Checked && oilChbox.Checked)
        {
            //Creating Variables sum to hold the value of the two
            double sum;

            sum = OIL_CHANGE + LUBE_JOB;

            //returning sum
            return sum;

        }
        //checking if the Oil is checked
        if (oilChbox.Checked)
        {
            return OIL_CHANGE;
        }

        //checking if the lube is checked
        if (lubeChbox.Checked)
        {
            return LUBE_JOB;
        }

            //just returning to get ride off the red line under the Method
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because if the first checkbox is checked, then first `if` statement is true, so you are **returning** value, thus ending the method.

You should replace your `if` statements, last one should become first, as it is most restrictive.